# Why does the line "int i, *ptr[3];" produce a segmentation fault in my code?

Tags: c

When running the below code, I am encountering a segmentation fault, which disappears when I remove the line `int i, *ptr[3];` I cannot understand why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum otype {INT, SYM, CONS};
typedef struct obj {
  enum otype type;
  struct obj *p[1];
} obj;

int main(void)
{
  char *str;
  strcpy(str, "test");
  printf("%c\n", str[0]); 

  struct obj obj1;
  obj1.type = INT;
  obj1.p[0] =  (obj*) malloc(sizeof(obj));
  obj1.p[0]->type = SYM;
  printf("%d\n", (obj1.p[0])->type);
  free(obj1.p[0]);

  int i, *ptr[3];

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: first UB is when you `strcpy(str, "test");` There is no space allocated for `str`

Comment: Your `str` is a pointer but no memory is allocated there. Then the `strcpy` copies the string `"test"` to ... wherever `str` happens to point to.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *str;
strcpy(str, "test");
```

This is already inviting problems, any behavior afterwards, is unpredictable.

More precisely you triggered [undefined behavior](http://www.slideshare.net/GiorgiMoniava/introduction-to-undefined-behavior-in-c-and-c?qid=a1e4ecc1-8319-4915-80eb-64a3ef2b3d2d&v=&b=&from_search=1), by trying to write "test" to some random location - e.g. location, where `str` points, but you never initialized `str` to point to valid memory.

You could have done

```
char str[100];
strcpy(str, "test");
```

and would be fine. Of course this way you have put upper length on string length: 99 characters + 1 for null terminator.

Comment: IMHO, talking about `strdup()` would be great.

Comment: @nouney I'll show him other approach since strdup involves also freeing

Comment: Thank you!! I removed strcpy(str, "test"); and the problem was solved. To me this error is really mysterious.

Comment: @nouney follow some of the links suggested by dbush and me

Comment: @james0011 You don't need to remove that line, just make sure `str` has enough space allocated (in this case 5 bytes, 4 for the text and 1 for the terminator), either via `malloc` or as shown in this answer. The mystery is you're writing data to an invalid place that you don't own and don't control.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
char *str;
strcpy(str, "test");
```

You declare a pointer without initializing it.  Then you pass it to `strcpy`, which attempts to dereference it to copy over the given string.  Since `str` is pointing to some unknown location, dereferencing it leads to [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means, among other things, that making seemingly unrelated changes can cause your program to crash (or not crash).

Instead of declaring `str` as a pointer, declare it as a character array so that it case a known size:

```
char str[50];
strcpy(str, "test");
```

Or simply initialize it when it is declared:

```
char str[] = "test";
```

Or:

```
char *str = "test";
```

Comment: Thank you!! I understand the problem now. It indeed solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for "str" before copying into 
    char *str 
    ->
    char str[4];
or use malloc.